# Function inside prototype not working

Tags: javascript

The onKeyDown function is not called when the keydown event is fired using the following code:

```
Game.prototype.setEventHandlers = function() {
    // Keyboard events
    window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);
    window.addEventListener("downup", onKeyUp, false);

    // Mouse events
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove, false);
    window.addEventListener("click", onMouseClick, false);

    // Window events
    window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize, false);

    var onKeyDown = function(e) {
        alert("HI!");
    };
}
```

If I replace it with the traditional function syntax it works just fine:

```
function onKeyDown() {
    alert("HI!");
}
```

Any ideas as to why the `var onKeyDown = function` syntax doesn't get the job done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Skwal: It doesn't matter where it's *declared*, it's where it's *initialized* that's the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your order of operations is the reason that the `window.addEventListener` calls are failing.

You're never passing the `onKeyDown` *function* in the first version, you're passing the value of the `onKeyDown` *variable*, which at the time of calling is `undefined`.

The reason the "traditional" version works, is due to what's called "hoisting".

`var` and `function` declarations are hoisted to the top of the function that they are written in.

Even though you might write code as:

<sub>Shortened for demonstration purposes</sub>

```
Game.prototype.setEventHandlers = function() {
    // Keyboard events
    window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);

    var onKeyDown = function(e) {
        alert("HI!");
    };
}
```

It actually executes as:

```
Game.prototype.setEventHandlers = function() {
    var onKeyDown;

    // Keyboard events
    window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);

    onKeyDown = function(e) {
        alert("HI!");
    };
}
```

If you were to use a function declaration instead

<sub>I.E.</sub>

```
Game.prototype.setEventHandlers = function() {
    // Keyboard events
    window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);

    function onKeyDown(e) {
        alert("HI!");
    }
}
```

The code actually executes as:

```
Game.prototype.setEventHandlers = function() {
    function onKeyDown(e) {
        alert("HI!");
    }

    // Keyboard events
    window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);
}
```

Code cleanup tools such as [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) will flag these sorts of inconsistencies. It's generally safer to write JS code in the way that it's going to execute. This helps prevent this sort of order of operations mistake.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Which function declaration would you say is better for this scenario?

Comment: @jskidd3, it doesn't make a difference. I recommend writing your code in the following order: variable declaration, function declaration, variable initialization, execution. In your case, you've put the variable initialization after the execution of the main function body. Which function declaration you choose to use is up to you.

Comment: @jskidd3: One objective reason to use the function *declaration* (your `function onKeyDown` example) rather than the function expression (your `var onKeyDown = function` example) is that the declaration gives the function a proper name, which can be useful in call stacks and such. (There is something called a named function expression, but it wouldn't be useful in your situation and doesn't work correctly on IE8...) As of the next version of the JavaScript spec, the expression form in your example would also give the function a real name, but not with current engines.

Answer (score 2):

> Any ideas as to why the var onKeyDown = function syntax doesn't get the job done?

At the moment you pass `onKeyDown` to `addEventListener`, it doesn't have a value yet. The assignment of the value takes place *at the end* of the function, after you already called `addEventListener`.

Move the assignment to the top:

```
Game.prototype.setEventHandlers = function() {

    var onKeyDown = function(e) {
        alert("HI!");
    };

    // Keyboard events
    window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);
    window.addEventListener("downup", onKeyUp, false);

    // Mouse events
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove, false);
    window.addEventListener("click", onMouseClick, false);

    // Window events
    window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize, false);

}
```

Comment: Ahh schoolboy error! Would you say it's better to assign the function to a variable in this scenario or is it more sensible to use the function() syntax that defines it at run time?

Comment: @jskidd3: That's really up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Function declarations (`function name() {}` style) have their variable and value hoisted to the top of the scope, but anonymous functions assigned to a variable (`var fn = function() {}` style) are not.  In your code, the variable declaration is hoisted but *not* the assignment of the function to that variable.

So your code is actually being parsed like this:

```
Game.prototype.setEventHandlers = function() {
  var onKeyDown;

  window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);

  onKeyDown = function(e) { ... };
};
```

So `onKeyDown` is undefined when you pass it to `addEventListener`.